# Behaviour of DEL with list taken from a dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, del

consider the following code

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

my_dict = {1:['Bernd','das','Brot'], 2:['Chili','das','Schaf'], 3:['Briegel','der','Busch']}
print my_dict

chili = my_dict[2]
print chili

del chili[2]
print chili
print my_dict
```

which produces the following output with my Python 2.7.5:

```
{1: ['Bernd', 'das', 'Brot'], 2: ['Chili', 'das', 'Schaf'], 3: ['Briegel', 'der', 'Busch']}
['Chili', 'das']
{1: ['Bernd', 'das', 'Brot'], 2: ['Chili', 'das'], 3: ['Briegel', 'der', 'Busch']}
```

As you can see, the list in the dict was also manipulated, so they appear to point to the same object/thing in memory.

Maybe I understand a basic Python principle wrong here (feel free to flame & point me towards the spec), but is this intended behaviour? And if it is, is there a way to delete and entry by index from a list taken from a dict without manipulating the original dict? Quite often I find out there is already an extraordinary simple Python way for doing stuff I try to accomplish with complicated code constructs.

I have a large dict here and I take lists out of it quite often, and I don't want to rebuild the dict each time I process the list in any way.

Thank you very much for your time & help,

Tobias

Comment: Yes, this is an intended behavior, and to get a copy of the list use slicing or `copy.deepcopy`.

Comment: The misunderstanding here is that you have not in fact "taken" the list from the dict at all; you have merely given it an additional name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is intended behaviour. Python names and entries in dictionaries and lists are mere *references* to the actual objects, stored in a big pile (the heap) in memory.

Thus, `my_dict[2]` and `chili` both refer to the same `list` object, and `list` objects are mutable. Deleting an entry from a `list` object means that all references to that object see the change.

If you want `chili` to not be the same list object, you must create a copy. You can create a shallow copy with either:

```
chili = my_dict[2][:]
```

as slicing from first to last index produces a new list object, or using:

```
chili = list(my_dict[2])
```

which produces a new `list` object, copying all references stored in the original sequence.

These create *shallow* copies; if anything in `my_dict[2]` is itself mutable you would still be manipulating an object shared between the `chili` list and the `my_dict[2]` list.

You can create a deep copy by using the [`copy.deepcopy()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy), which recursively produces copies of objects.

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
 chili = my_dict[2]
```

Then `chili` is a reference to the same object as `my_dict[2]`. So modifying `chili` will modify `my_dict`.

You can copy a list:

```
  chili = list(my_dict[2])
```

Now `del chili[2]` won't modify `my_dict`.